# How filter address based on Multiple Columns in T-SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I want to search street address based on multiple columns in a database table. 
 For example I want to "street name, city name, zip code" etc from a table structure is as follows

```
     Address1 [nvarchar]
     Address2 [nvarchar]   
     CityName [nvarchar]
     ZipCode [numeric]
```

Case 1:
       User Can Seearch : a) Street Name,Washingtone DC,2837 =seachCon
                      or :b) Washing = seachCon
                      or  c) Zip Code = seachCon

Query 1: a) works other b and c does not works

```
Select *from AddressTable 
          Where seachCon like '%'+streetName+'%' or seachCon like '%'+cityName+'%' or seachCon like '%'+zipCode+'%'
```

Query 2: a) does note works while b) and c) works

```
Select *from AddressTable 
          Where streetName lik '%'+searchCon+'%' or cityName like '%'+searchCon+'%' or zipCode like '%'+searchCon+'
```

*** I want a query either works on full address or partial

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: If that's what you want then go ahead and do that.  If you have issues along the way, that would be the time to post here, showing us what you've done and explaining how it behaves differently to what you expect.

Comment: jmc thanks for reply.
Above query has problem 
1.  If user enters full city name only City Search then it works. eg. When user enters Washingtone it works but when user enters only Washin it does not works. Query is select *from address where 'address,city name,zip' like '%'+address+'%' or 'address,city name,zip' like '%'+cityname+'%' or 'address,city name,zip' like '%'+zipCode+'%' 

2, When I replace conditions of question as select *from address where address like '%address,city name,zip%' ... etc  works on Washi,Washingtone but note on 'address,city name,zip' :)

Comment: Dear  jmcilhinney,
Please check I try to explain my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Declare @Search varchar(150)
    Set @Search = 'Wash 2837'

        Select Top 100*
         From  AddressTable 
         Where Address1+' '+Address2+' '+CityName +' '+ZipCode Like '%'+replace(ltrim(rtrim(@Search)),' ','%')
         Order By 1,2,3
```

This would return all records which contain WASH and 2837 (in that sequence).

Personally, I would put this in a stored procedure or udf with a @Search parameter. The @Search would be transformed prior to execution